# php admin session control error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a site trying to add login system, everything goes good except session on admin/index.php

here is the regular session page protect for all type of users it works for protecting pages but cant control user levels

```
session_start();

// If session variable is not set it will redirect to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])){
  header("location: login.php");
  exit;
}
```

here is my session control for admin user.which I tried.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']['ifadmin'] == '1' || empty($_SESSION['username']['if admin'] == '1')){
  header("location: login.php");
  exit;
}
```

normal users
index.php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']['ifadmin'] == '2' || empty($_SESSION['username']['if admin'] == '2')){
  header("location: login.php");
  exit;
}
```

and this is the error I am having

```
 Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in D:\wamp\www\site\index.php on line 5
```

working variables of the session for me

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['ifadmin']!=1){
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
```

How to check if emty now ?

Comment: You cannot do comparison operations inside isset() and empty() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php , http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Lol. Thanks bro, I checked that examples but couldn’t understand anything, I am not a coder it’s my personal page playing with it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']=='1') && $_SESSION['user_id'] != '')
 {
  header("location: login.php");
   }
    else if(isset($_SESSION['admin_id']=='2') && $_SESSION['admin_id'] != '') 
    {
     header("location: login.php"); 
     }
```

Comment: having same error bro Fatal error: `Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)` @PHP Geek